# Obscure error while transcoding a video with FFMPEG

Tags: ruby, heroku, ffmpeg

thanks for taking a moment to look at this FFMPEG error i'm having. I'm trying to transcode any video file, recorded in portrait mode and crop it to a square using the top portion and then size it down to 600x600 square. Here is the command i'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input-video.mov -filter_complex '[0] crop=1080:1080:0:0, scale=600:600, split=2[out1][out2]' -map '[out1]' video/transcoded-video.mp4 -map '[out2]' -qscale:v 6 thumbnails/thumb_%03d.png
```

Here are the errors:

```
[swscaler @ 0x2502260] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[swscaler @ 0x250a2b0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[swscaler @ 0x2512300] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] [Eval @ 0x7fff769243e0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
```

Here is the output:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-06-02-5711e4f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
 built on Jun  2 2013 07:38:40 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
 configuration: --enable-shared --disable-asm --prefix=/app/vendor/ffmpeg
 libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
 libavcodec     55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
 libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
 libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
 libavfilter     3. 74.101 /  3. 74.101
 libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
 libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/app/downloads/bf951fbc8322d9010d679e656ccda330b6f19f36.mov':
 Metadata:
   major_brand     : qt  
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: qt  
   creation_time   : 2016-07-01 19:27:37
 Duration: 00:00:04.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17881 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17874 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
   Metadata:
     rotate          : 90
     creation_time   : 2016-07-01 19:27:37
     handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
[swscaler @ 0x2502260] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[swscaler @ 0x250a2b0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[swscaler @ 0x2512300] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] [Eval @ 0x7fff769243e0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[NULL @ 0x24e9dd0] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
Output #0, mp4, to '/app/outputs/2091/bf951fbc8322d9010d679e656ccda330b6f19f36.mp4':
 Metadata:
   major_brand     : qt  
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: qt  
   Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 600x600, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
Output #1, image2, to '/app/outputs/2091/thumbs/thumb_%03d.png':
 Metadata:
   major_brand     : qt  
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: qt  
   Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24, 600x600, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
 Stream #0:0 (h264) -> crop
 split:output0 -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
 split:output1 -> Stream #1:0 (png)
```

Thanks again for looking at this and anything will help.

Comment: This is a forum for programming related issues, not how to use a command line application. There are other forums that are probably a better fit for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's fine to ask a question like this here. Stackoverflow has over 10,000 questions tagged as FFMPEG. Not to mention, stackoverflow suggested the ffmpeg topic. Thanks for your help @micker

Comment: You're using a very old version, and one which doesn't have libx264 included. Try with a recent build.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya. This fixed my problem. *hat tip*

Comment: @ZiggidyCreative it's nice to resolve the question by posting an aswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old version, and one which doesn't have libx264 included. Try with a recent build. – @Mulvya